# Running skype javascript in a function

Tags: javascript, html, skype

So I'm trying to execute this in such a way that the skype button only become visible once this function is called from my html page. 
function setContent(map) {

```
    var contentString = /*'<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
        'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
        'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
        'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
        '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
        'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
        'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
        'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
        'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
        'Heritage Site.</p>'+
        '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
        '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+ */
  '<div id="SkypeButton_Call_Dominic_Martin123_1">'+
  ' <script type="text/javascript">' + 
      ' Skype.ui({ '+
      ' "name": "dropdown",'+
      ' "element": "SkypeButton_Call_Dominic_Martin123_1",'+
       '"participants": ["Dominic_Martin123"],'+
     ' "imageSize": 24'+
      '});'+
    '</script>'+
   '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: 51.376537,  lng: -2.327279},
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

I keep getting an 'EOF' error and i also feel as tho I'm not doing something right here anyway. The skype javascript seems basic enough, and my page is laid out correctly (enough for it to work ) as it works without it. How can i implement this correctly?  I think its a case of embedding it in the code?

Comment: Will you mind `formatting` your code ?

Comment: Wait.. why can't I edit this?

Comment: Does this code live in a external JS file or is it sitting inline?

Comment: Replace `'</script>'+` with `'</scr'+'ipt>'+` and see if it works.